# Arcsoft Connect Daemon stopped working

Tags: windows-7, arcsoft

On one of our computers the error message `Arcsoft Connect Daemon has stopped working` offers two choices: either to check online for a solution or to close the program. In fact the solution is never found so the only option is to close.

Whatever choice, if then I go to Arcsoft in the services list it says it is running and is set to automatic start up. However it *isn't* running even though it says it is. (I can tell because the computer says there is no connection to a shared printer.) Here are the full error message details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: ACDaemon.exe
  Application Version:  1.1.0.49
  Application Timestamp:    4cc808ec
  Fault Module Name:    ACDaemon.exe
  Fault Module Version: 1.1.0.49
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4cc808ec
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0001af76
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: e9e5
  Additional Information 2: e9e5e2773a3411d0bd2905e0d7d64672
  Additional Information 3: df38
  Additional Information 4: df38fdf8034d489b6aff8f342f09fcb5

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Any advice much appreciated. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I installed a  program called PhotoStudio 5.5. When I uninstalled it, this message came up as well. I located the exe file for this message here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft\Connection Service\Bin\ACService.exe
```

I deleted the file but found the message still came up when rebooting. Seeing how the program was removed, I saw no reason not to remove the whole folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft`) to the recycle bin.

This seems to have worked.